# VS Code doesn't find fish if called via Automator

Tags: terminal, automator, visual-studio-code, fish

I've using `/usr/local/bin/fish` as my default shell, which works fine both in Terminal and in the Terminal within VS Code.

I was recently trying to add an Automator action to open VS Code from a given file path by using a simple Automator workflow with a "Run Shell Script" action: `open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args "$*"`.

[image: Where's Fish?]

Automator opens VSCode properly and in the right path, but once it does I can't use the VSCode terminal as it returns an error of

> The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "fish" does not exist.

How can I make VSCode find `fish` when started via Automator?

Comment: Does it work if you change the default in Terminal back to bash or zsh?

Comment: I installed fish using Homebrew.

Comment: How did you make fish the default shell? Installing it does not make a shell the default.

Comment: @mmmmmm something like this: brew install fish  
curl -L https://get.oh-my.fish | fish
sudo bash -c 'echo /usr/local/bin/fish >> /etc/shells'
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/fish

Comment: Ah, reread your question now, it's not about Automator but about "paths opened using this action don't run the VSCode terminal properly". Do you set `fish` anywhere within VSCode? Does the VSCode terminal manage to run `fish` correctly if you launch it directly (without the action)?

Comment: @nohillside YES!  The terminal does run `fish` correctly if I launch it without the action.  I think the problem is that Automator starts VS code in some kind of `zsh` context, and then can't understand why I'm trying to run `fish` in the terminal.

Comment: I made a rather heavy-handed edit to your question, please add any details I may have overseen when deleting stuff.

Comment: For me this looks like an environment problem (meaning the environment you have in Terminal differs from the one VS Code sees when it is called via Automator). If you start VS Code first (so the internal Terminal does work) and then use your Automator workflow, do you also get the error?

Comment: I have my shell set to `/opt/homebrew/bin/bash`, so this should trigger the same issue. If I use your action from above (with `/bin/bash` as the shell), VSCode Terminal works without an issue (and uses `/opt/homebrew/bin/bash` as expected). Strange stuff. Which version of macOS are you running?

Comment: @nohillside starting VSCode first does not solve the problem.  As to your second point...interesting.  Huh, not sure why that would be unless the OS is somehow making a bash/bash comparison.

Comment: And I'm using Monterrey.

Comment: I also tried with fish in the meantime, but then VSCode didn't realize I switched shells (so it kept using bash when launched again).